# SQL Developer Read Only Test Mode

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer to construct a PL/SQL file for Oracle DB updates and I want to test them out, but I dont have UPDATE privileges. Is there some type of test mode that would pretend I do and save things locally? Or do I have to export the data I need into a local DB and test it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to have a database where you do have `update` privileges to run your test or some way in your environment to cause your script to be run (i.e. sending it to a DBA to run against a lower environment, checking it in to your build tool to have the build tool run the script against the lower environment, etc.).  SQL Developer is just a client that connects to other databases, it doesn't include a database that you could run the script against.